# how can I prevent nautilus from running when I plug in a USB stick?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, xfce, usb-drive

I run XFCE4 on Ubuntu 11.10.

When I plug in a USB memory stick, I get two new windows popping up, both showing the contents of the memory stick.  One is Thunar (which I want) and one is nautilus (which I don't).

Before I plug in the stick, nautilus isn't running at all.  Something is spawning it, but I don't know what, or how to stop it.

This is what the **Nautilus->Edit->Preferences** dialog looks like.  There's no **Media** tab:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 12.04, You can follow this procedure:

- First install `dconf-tools` by the command `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`.
- Then open the `dconf-editor` by pressing `Alt-F2` and typing `dconf-editor`.
- In the `dconf-editor` window, go to the following steps:

  ```
  org -> gnome -> desktop -> media-handling
  ```

  then uncheck `automount_open` options
- Exit `dconf-editor`.

---

[Source: This page on Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11905603&postcount=2)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, though the link can answer the question, It is preferable to include the details here

Comment: in dconf-editor for me, there is no media-handling option, and I can't find automount_open anywhere.

Comment: if you dont want to install new software , you can use the command  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using nautilus in xfce, you can remove nautilus from synaptic.

Else, open

**Nautilus ->Edit ->Preferences-> Media**

and set every option to "Do Nothing" and

Check the option "**Never prompt or start programs on media insertion**"

Uncheck "**Browse media when Inserted**"

Comment: I don't think removing nautilus is a good idea, because I think that will stop it working for the other people who use the computer.  I tried uncheckinging that option, but couldn't find it.  I added a screenshot of the Preferences window to my question - there's no Media tab.

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot in the question, there is no media tab in preferences.