# How to prevent nautilus from launching?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, nautilus, mount, i3-wm

I'm running i3-wm under a gnome session in 12.04.

Nautilus is not normally running.

I regularly loop-mount ISO and other filesystem image files, and every time I do this nautilus pops up both a desktop window and a window opened at the new mount point.

Uninstalling nautilus is not an option -- I tried this, but apt reports that dozens of packages depend on it (directly and indirectly).

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/114155/9675) is similar, but only talks about preventing launching on USB stick insertion. I don't want nautilus to run, ever -- removal would be ok with me if it didn't require uninstalling the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run in terminal :

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`

Comment: +1 This is the answer as it prevents the desktop from launch in other apps that call on nautilus (e.g. Sublime).

Comment: @bstpierre Please mark the post as the right answer (assuming this worked for you).

Answer (score 1):

What I did was creating an executable script to open Nautilus for me:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/nfm
```

Copy and paste this in:

```
#!/bin/bash
nautilus  --browser --no-desktop &
```

Finally make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/nfm
```

In your i3 config file, wherever you put it, make sure you run this:

```
# nautilus as a daemon!
nautilus --no-default-window --no-desktop &
```

Comment: How does this prevent nautilus from being run? Did you even read the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the permission to execute nautilus like this in terminal:

```
sudo chmod a-x /usr/bin/nautilus
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable automount with the dconf editor. You can find a good tutorial right [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences).